# Using AngularJS to create a dynamic table - need help going from success/error method to .then() method

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I recently asked a question where I was advised to start using **AngularJS** to dynamically create a table. Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of **AngularJS** (or coding at all), and was following a tutorial which led to deprecated code. Essentially, from what I can gather, the success and error method used in `$http` should be replaced with a `.then()` method. As my code currently stands, all I am being returned is: `{{ cribs | json }}`.

**My html code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ng-cribs Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>    
  <body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      </br>
      <div class="well" ng-repeat="crib in cribs">
          <h3> {{ crib.name }} </h3>
          <p><strong>Contact Number: </strong>{{ crib.contactNumber }}</p>
          <p><strong>Email Address: </strong>{{ crib.email }}</p>
          <p><strong>Pass Number: </strong>{{ crib.passNumber }}</p>
      </div>
      <pre>{{ cribs | json }}</pre>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/cribsController.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/cribsFactory.js"></script>    
</html>
```

My js code (in the same directory):

```
angular.module('ngCribs', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

My AngularJS factory code (in a "scripts" subfolder):

```
angular
    .module('ngCribs')
    .factory('cribsFactory', function($http) {
        function getCribs() {
            return $http.get('data/data.json');
        }

        return {
            getCribs: getCribs
        }
    });
```

My AngularJS controller code (also in the "scripts" directory):

```
angular
    .module('ngCribs')
    .controller('cribsController', function($scope, cribsFactory){
        $scope.cribs;

        cribsFactory.getCribs().success(function(data) {
            $scope.cribs = data;
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        // $scope.hello = 'Hello wo!';
    });
```

And my JSON file (in a separate directory called "data"):

```
[
    {
      "name": "Joel Doe",
      "dob": "17-03-1994",
      "houseNumber": "31",
      "postcode": "LS4 2RS",
      "contactNumber": "07941405771",
      "email": "joeldoe@outlook.com",
      "passNumber": "01",
    },
    {
      "name": "Harry Doe",
      "dob": "21-04-1992",
      "houseNumber": "43",
      "postcode": "LS2 1DH",
      "contactNumber": "0797651387",
      "email": "harrydoe@outlook.com",
      "passNumber": "02",
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "dob": "19-12-1993",
      "houseNumber": "65",
      "postcode": "LS1 6EK",
      "contactNumber": "07979804398",
      "email": "janedoe@outlook.com",
      "passNumber": "03",
    },
]
```

I have also included a link to my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVyXzp

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Code in **cribsController** should be changed to

```
cribsFactory.getCribs().then(function(data) {
      $scope.cribs = data;

  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the guidance. Replacing that code so the cribsController.js reads:

angular
  .module('ngCribs')
  .controller('cribsController', function($scope, cribsFactory){

      $scope.cribs;

      cribsFactory.getCribs().then(function(data) {
            $scope.cribs = data;

        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
//    $scope.hello = 'Hello wo!';
  })
  ;

Except where I was being returned {{ cribs | json }}, I am being returned nothing. Could you offer any further guidance?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot test the code completely, because there is not data received on the link, which you provided.

Comment: What I can suggest to do - insert ``console.log(data);` in the first(success) callback inside `then`. Also check console for the errors from the second(error) callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have few more issues with the code, so I refined them as well.

Working code - http://plnkr.co/edit/TM8jYldnE6DCquemSkX7?p=preview

Code-

```
angular
  .module('ngCribs')
  .controller('cribsController', function($scope, cribsFactory){

      $scope.cribs = {};
      cribsFactory.getCribs().then(function(data) {  
          $scope.cribs = data.data;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error); // Handle the error here
      })
})
```

Things I enhanced to make it working -

1. Cleaned JSON to validate, please check as it was not valid.
2. Remove unnecessary `<script>` tags and HTML elements in `index.html`.
3. Added Error handling code for `then()`.
4. It is a good practice to initialize your scope variable at start no just `$scope.cribs`.

Let me know in case of any query.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response!

I've copied the code into a new project and alls I'm getting returned is: {}

Could you perhaps offer some further guidance?

Edit: I copied the code you provided from my text editor (atom) into the website you linked. It's working in the website, but not on my local host, so I assume a package or something has failed to load correctly. My apologies I cannot be more succinct in my query!!

Comment: @Rumbubble, sure ..have you checked my code as its working, or let me know what you are trying to do

Comment: Of course - basically, to help teach myself code, I'm creating an app in which if an employee forgets their work pass and requires a temporary one, their details can be entered and the receptionist/security can assign them a pass number. This data is transferred into a table once the information has been inputted and confirmed, with their name, pass number, and any other relevant information.

I have checked your code - please see above response (I've made an edit)! Thanks again!

Comment: @Rumbubble If you are talking about - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVyXzp , please check line - `$http.get('data/data.json');` ..now in your example this path doesn't exists so better you take this whole JSON into a variable or move to file like I created `data.json` file separately, please refer my code

Comment: @Rumbubble let me know if you still have any doubt remaining

Comment: Forgive me, but I've copied your code directly to Atom, and when I run it I get {}. When I copy the code from Atom back into the website you provided, i get returned the results I want. There is now no       "return $http.get('data/data.json');" code in my file. Thanks again!

Comment: @Rumbubble can u share the screenshots

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyeA5.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LoSU.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CpHI.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr12l.jpg
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B6uN.jpg
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRYjY.jpg
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQObP.jpg
  [8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnvu7.jpg
  [9]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARW0t.jpg
  [10]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Ubl.jpg
  [11]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/72C29.jpg
  [12]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW2Vl.jpg
  [13]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAz9w.jpg

Comment: Screenshots 1-5 are my original code which I submitted to StackOverflow. Screenshot 6 is my result of running this code.
Screenshot 7-9 is the code provided by yourself in the website, with the correct result displayed. Screenshot 10-12 is the code of yours I copied into Atom. And screenshot 13 is the result I obtain when attempting to run the copied code.

Seriously, thanks again.